# How can i Execute query as update or insert on the basis of field value

Tags: mysql

I have table with fields

```
name quantity  expiry
a     2        14/12/2012    
b     3        13/2/2013
```

If name exist and quantity is  0 than query  will work as update query other wise work as insert query . More than one row can exist with same name but will have different expiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

EDIT: I'm not sure if the "if quantity is 0" part can be accomplished with that, though, so this might not fully answer your question.

Comment: Can you suggest me any query for this.

Comment: above query  you suggested can't help me out  because many rows with same name can exist but with different expiry so i can't make name as primary key.

Comment: You can make a unique index of (name, expiry) which will allow you to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause.